# PFQueryTableViewController with 3 Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a 'Game' table in my parse database with the following relevant columns:

- isOver (Boolean)
- whoseTurn (Relation:_User) (Games can have multiple players, so it can be more than one person's turn at the same time)
- players (Relation:_User)

I need to query this table and display the results in 3 separate sections of the tableview:

- 'My Turn'
- 'Their Turn'
- 'Game Over'

I was thinking of using the following query coupled with some of the code in the answer given here: https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    [query whereKey:@"players" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    //BREAK UP INTO SECTIONS
    [query orderByDescending:@"isOver"];
    [query addDescendingOrder:@"whoseTurn"];
```

How can I display the results in 3 different tableview sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question contains two challenges, and that's one too many for the `PFQueryTableVC`.  The post you site makes evident that you can get sections with a little extra overriding, but what's not covered there is that your model depends on related objects (users) via a PFRelation.

That extra requirement rules out the PFQueryTableVC because it assumes your table can be fetched in a single query, but yours depends on fetching those two relations columns.

This is going to force you to roll your own with a plain old `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` as its view's subview.  (Notice I don't recommend `UITableViewController` here... just like `PFQueryTableVC`, it often generates more effort than convenience, though you could probably get away with it here).

The gist of how to do it is this:  in succession, query the games table, then it's `whoseTurn` relation, then it's `players` relation.  With that data, you'll be able to segregate the found games into three arrays, corresponding exactly to your table view sections: `gamesThatAreOver`, `gamesThatAreUsersTurn`, `gamesThatAreOtherUsersTurn`.

You can put those arrays in another, call it `model`.  Tell your table view that you have `self.model.count` sections (that will always be `==3`), and that the number of rows at an index path is `self.model[indexPath.section].count`

Your version of object at index path will give you a game, and will look like this:  `self.model[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];`

PS - I think freeing yourself from the "convenience" (aka constraint) of the parse provided class is going to be a net positive anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and detailed answer! Now, could I not just use a PFQTVC and fetch these relations in the objectsDidLoad method, and create my arrays there, or would it be easier to do it the way you suggested, with my own ViewController?

Comment: I investigated that real quick before I answered.  I think not.  The queryForTable method wants a PFQuery returned.  The superclass executes that query and then calls objectsDidLoad.  There's some chance that you could execute the relation queries there, but it looks to me like the whole thing is wired to run synchronously at that point

Comment: But i guess you could try.  The trick is, to not crash because the super thinks you're all done loading when objectsDidLoad fires.  For me, when I find myself having to play tricks on the super, its time to leave the super.

Comment: I know I have executed queries in objectsDidLoad in the past, and it does slow down the loading just a bit, but it works. The queries I have done in the past involve querying another class where the pointer is equal to the objects in self.objects, but that was not for creating sections in the tableview. So, either way, it looks like I need to split up my 3 sections into 3 different arrays, yes? Since I have relied so much on PFQTVC in the past, where would I execute the query in my own VC? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, definitely, to support a table with sections you want an array of arrays.  The outer array represents sections and the inners represent the rows of each section.  I hadn't considered running the relations queries synchronously in objectsDidLoad.  That would remove all of my concerns about being out of synch with the superclass (but I never do it because I *never* do network tasks synchronously.  If you can live with the little UI freeze during those calls then you might be good to go, but its not considered good style).

Comment: I need to break out of the habit of doing my network tasks synchronously...I think I will try to do this in my own VC. Since I have relied so much on PFQTVC in the past, where would I execute the query in my own VC? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: viewWillAppear is more common.  You can opt not to query if you already have data

Comment: I believe the objects will be cached, so they will only need to be queried for if they are not in the cache. Thank you for all of your help and explanation!

Comment: Just a note: I began using a UIViewController as you suggested, but I ran into a problem not being able to implement a refresh control elegantly, so I had to switch to a UITableViewController.

Comment: It is easier with the table vc, but altogether possible without.