# Nested Query Blocks to load data into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, parse-platform

I have a UIViewController with a tableView as a subview. The tableview will have 3 sections, and I used the answer to my question [PFQueryTableViewController with 3 Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422402/pfquerytableviewcontroller-with-3-sections) to accomplish this, but the data is not getting loaded into the table. I am executing my query in the background in viewWillAppear. I fear that this is due to the nested query blocks. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    PFQuery *gameQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
    [gameQuery whereKey:@"players" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [gameQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [gameQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){

        self.myTurn = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.theirTurn = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.gameOver = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.allGames = [NSArray array];

        for(PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            if([object objectForKey:@"isOver"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES])
            {
                [self.gameOver addObject:object];
            }

            else
            {

                PFRelation *relation = [object relationForKey:@"whoseTurn"];
                PFQuery *relQuery = [relation query];
                [relQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *userObjects, NSError *error1){


                    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for(PFUser *user in userObjects)
                    {
                        [arr addObject:user.objectId];
                    }

                    if([arr containsObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId])
                    {
                       [self.myTurn addObject:object];
                    }

                    else
                        [self.theirTurn addObject:object];

                }];
            }

        }

        self.allGames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.myTurn, self.theirTurn, self.gameOver, nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.allGames count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[self.allGames objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *object = self.allGames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"numPlayers"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you set some breakpoints to check that everything gets effectively called, including code in your subquery?

Comment: @Romain I had a bunch of log statements that I removed when I pasted the code here. Everything is called, it just seems as though the arrays are empty at the time I create the "allGames" array.

Comment: Your Parse queries run asynchronously, and as such, the `allGames` is initialized with 3 empty arrays at the time you call `reloadData`. Since your data structure is known (an array comprised of 3 arrays), why not initializing it with 3 empty arrays *before* running your Parse queries and then, in callback blocks, updating it directly (with proper thread synchronization) and finally calling `reloadData`? This will end up in calling `reloadData` much more often, but iOS should be OK with it, and if not, you'll still be able to find optimizations later with your working code anyway.

Comment: @Romain They are initially empty, but why would they be empty at the time I call reloadData as I placed that statement at the end of the block? Can you post some code for the solution you suggested?

Comment: That's actually true for `self.gameOver`, but not for the other ones. Does `self.gameOver` actually contain at least one object when you call `self.allGames = [NSArray arrayWith...];`? If not, try to put some data into Parse that would make an object appear in this array. The other two are getting filled in asynchronous blocks, so after the `allGames` initialization, probably, that's why they are still empty at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you could try to do:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *gameQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
    [gameQuery whereKey:@"players" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [gameQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [gameQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){

        @synchronized(self.allGames) {
            self.allGames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], [NSMutableArray array], nil];
            // These two instance variables contain values used in asynchronous blocks, to know how much responses are still expected
            self.expectedNbGames = [objects count];
            self.fetchedNbGames = 0;
        }

        for(PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            if([object objectForKey:@"isOver"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES])
            {
                @synchronized(self.allGames) {
                    [((NSMutableArray *)self.allGames[2]) addObject:object];
                    self.fetchedNbGames++;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                PFRelation *relation = [object relationForKey:@"whoseTurn"];
                PFQuery *relQuery = [relation query];
                [relQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *userObjects, NSError *error1){

                    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for(PFUser *user in userObjects)
                    {
                        [arr addObject:user.objectId];
                    }

                    @synchronized(self.allGames) {
                        if([arr containsObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId])
                        {
                            [((NSMutableArray *)self.allGames[0]) addObject:object];
                        }

                        else
                            [((NSMutableArray *)self.allGames[1]) addObject:object];
                        }

                        self.fetchedNbGames++;
                        if (self.fetchedNbGames == self.expectedNbGames)
                        {
                            // We have now received the last expected response, it's time to sort everything again in descending order based on the "createdAt" value
                            NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO];
                            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
                            // self.allGames[0] is already sorted anyway because it's been left untouched from the initial PFQuery
                            self.allGames[1] = [self.allGames[1] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
                            self.allGames[2] = [self.allGames[2] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
                            // And... reload one last time!
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [self.tableView reloadData];
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
                }];
            }

        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    @synchronized(self.allGames) {
        return [self.allGames count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    @synchronized(self.allGames) {
        return [[self.allGames objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    @synchronized(self.allGames) {
        PFObject *object = self.allGames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"numPlayers"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The `@synchronized()` construct is used to ensure thread-safety, because you will be accessing (both reading and writing) the `sell.allGames` array from different threads (the main thread, but also asynchronous blocks coming from Parse replies).

Note that we're dispatching the `reloadData` multiple times from the asynchronous blocks because there is currently no way in your code to know when all the blocks have finished running. We need to dispatch this call on the main thread, because it will trigger UI updates, and those always have to be done on the main thread.

See if this works, and maybe you'll be able to improve it a little bit using properties for example (to avoid writing `@synchronized()` every time you're using `self.allGames`).

**UPDATE**: I've improved my answer by providing a way to re-sort everything after all responses have been received. This process involves the creation of two new instance variables (integers named `fetchedNbGames` and `expectedNbGames`) that have to be updated and compared to each other after every response received from Parse. Once all responses have been received, the results array can be re-sorted (it might have been disordered because of requests being sent and handled asynchronously) and the table view refreshed again.

This is untested and there is probably a lot of room for improvements, but it's up to you to tune it to your needs, you get the basic idea.

Also see [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021880/findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-gets-data-from-parse-but-data-only-exists-ins?rq=1) for a more visual explanation of your problem related to threading and asynchronous calls.

Comment: If I changed my columns in parse to be arrays of PFObjects instead of Relations, I would not have to run the second background query, right? I would just be able to retrieve the array and compare the objects.

Comment: I guess so, yes. But your current design probably has its reasons, too. Did you try the solution I provided?

Comment: Yes, I am implementing it now, but my internet connection is poor so the queries are not executing.

Comment: Edit: This solution seems to be working pretty well! How will the load time be affected when there are say 100 objects returned from the query?

Comment: There seem to be some issues arising with this method, now. The objects do not always load in the correct order, even though I specify the order here [gameQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"]; any ideas?

Comment: This is kind of normal, since you're running a lot of asynchronous queries at almost the same time, but you're not guaranteed that Parse will respond in the same order. Two ways you can handle this: sequence your calls (but it will take more time to load!), or re-sort data on the client side, once all queries are done. In both situations you will probably need to store new variables in your class to be able to know when the execution is finished. I can try to update my answer when I'm on a desktop computer, if you want.

Comment: That would be great! Then I will mark it as correct :) As I mentioned earlier, if I change changed the relation columns to arrays, I would not have multiple asynchronous queries, and the objects would be returned in the correct order, yes?

Comment: I posted an edit, but it's untested. Tell me if it works and I'll adapt the answer otherwise. Of course, if your app needs to fetch tens of Parse objects, the user will begin to notice it and performance will probably take a hit. As you suggested in your comment, you might need to consider another data model to fetch everything in a single Parse query. So yes, you could change your relation into an array, but it's up to you to decide what's best for your app based on your data model and what's contained inside your relations. Good luck :)